# Voice changing chips

Tags: electricity

I have seen this video: https://youtu.be/FMsdEfou_kc?t=44 on youtube. And I was wondering if something like these voice changing chips are electrically possible.
I have tried googling for something like that, but I can't find anything. For example, I would like to change female voice to male.

Comment: Fixed, see my edited question

Comment: still wildly unrelated. "electricity" is not a tag that describes your post.

Comment: also, really: trying to find sense in movie-depicted technology is not an engineering question. Please ask something that can have an authorative answer and is engineering.

Comment: I can't find a better tag. And it **is** an engineering question. I want to know, how to do it, if it is possible

Comment: Updated, is it ok now?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a "voice pitch shifter" commonly used in audio production software and also in guitar effects. These are not a "chip" but rather a sound processing system. Most sound terrible.

Comment: Google "autotune". It's a much more complex than a single chip. And it's responsible for a lot of terrible sounding music.  But it can also produce much more subtle effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no electronic way to affect the voice through the throat with full control. That's because the sound is the property of the whole system air, its flow, all tissues, resonances in all cavities (which a human deforms as he talks) and what time dependent tension is caused by the muscles. How in the hell a couple of buttons can externally control so big number of nerve activity and alter the hard facts (=sizes)

There are available throat vibrators for those who have permanently lost their own voice, but they sound like robots wih no richness of human speech. Some musicians have used a device which works as amp speaker but generate vibrations in user's throat. A guitarist can talk and sing with the voice of his guitar. Simplest versions are a flexible tube which is held in one's mouth and the other end is in a speaker cabinet.

In addition all kind of vocoders exist. They can alter voices which are captured by microphones but the result is still recognizable speech. They do not control the formation of the original voice.

I have used in recordings modern pitch shifting software to fix sloppy singing, generating choirs and weird sounding vocals. In some rare occasions large shifts have generated a voice which still sounds human. Mostly only small shifts sound plausible.